# How do I set -Dfile.encoding within ant's build.xml?

Tags: java, ant, character-encoding, javac

I've got java source files with iso-8859-1 encoding.  When I run *ant*, I get "warning: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8".  I can avoid this if I run *ant -Dfile.encoding=iso-8859-1* or add *encoding="ISO-8859-1"* to each javac statement.

Is there a way to set the property globally within build.xml?  *<property name="file.encoding" value="ISO-8859-1">* does not work.  I know that I can add a foo=ISO-8859-1 property and set encoding="${foo}" to each javac statement, but I'm trying to avoid that.

Comment: The problem should be solved in four places simultaneously: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34225997/715269

Answer (score 37, accepted):

A few options:

1. add `-Dfile.encoding=iso-8859-1` to your `ANT_OPTS` environment variable
2. use `<presetdef>` to setup defaults for all of your `<javac>` invocations

Answer (score 76):

If you've got files encoded in a particular way, it's probably best to tell javac that rather than forcing the whole JVM to use a particular encoding.  The [javac task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html) has an encoding attribute for this reason.

```
<javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${build.classes.dir}" encoding="iso-8859-1" />
```

But really, you should just convert the source files to UTF-8.  Everything tastes better in UTF-8.  :)

Comment: Even if you convert the contents to UTF-8, you sometimes have to have a clean environment (LC_ALL=C) and there that comes pretty much handy.

Answer (score 3):

Before changing build file i am getting java compile error like below.

ApplicationConstant.java:73: **error: unmappable character for encoding ascii**
 `public static final String INVALID_MDTVERSION_SECOND = " This not compatible with the serverâ€™s Version";`

I have encounter this error when I used to have ant java target as:

```
 <javac encoding="ascii"...>
```

Than i have change as below

```
<javac encoding="iso-8859-1" ...>
```

This issue got solved.

Answer (score 1):

Ant itself cannot set system properties, but if you really want to, you can write a java program which sets the system property, and execute that from within Ant.