# How do I set file.encoding for a junit test in ant?

Tags: java, ant, junit, file-encodings

I'm not quite done with [file.encoding and ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339352/how-do-i-set-dfile-encoding-within-ants-build-xml).   How do I set the *file.encoding* for junit tests in ant?  The *junit* ant task doesn't support the *encoding* attribute like the *javac* task does.

I've tried running «ant -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8» and «ANT_OPTS="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8" ant» without success.  System.getProperty("file.encoding") within a test still returns *MacRoman*.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

JUnit supports a child element `<jvmarg ...>` which should do what you want.

```
<junit fork="yes">
  <jvmarg value="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"/>
  ...
</junit>
```

I assume you were using the `fork=yes` attribute since this starts a new JVM for the test run, thus the parameters you send into ant at the command line `ant -Dfoo=bar` do not necessarily propagate to the JVM running the tests.