# Ant Umlauts within description attribute

Tags: ant, character-encoding

Is there a way to show german umlauts like äÄöÖüÜ in the description attribute?

```
<target name="mytarget" description="Some fancy german umlauts äÄöÖüÜ">
    <!-- Stuff -->
</target>
```

If i call my target:

```
machine:html root$ ant -p
```

The console prompt looks like

```
mytarget     some fancy german umlauts ??????.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link:  [encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339352/how-do-i-set-dfile-encoding-within-ants-build-xml)

Essentially it suggest supplying a command line argument to ant that specifies which encoding to use for the tasks.  If that is not where the issue is, validate that your console has the proper encoding on it.  This can be tested by trying to generate a diacritic within the console.  If that fails, change the encoding on your console/terminal.