# Is there a way to build UTF-8 source files using ant

Tags: java, ant, encoding

I have UTF-8 string literals hardcoded in my java files.
Eclipse builds this application correctly, so resulting class files contains those strings in UTF-8. 
But If use ant build.xml, resulting class files contains strings with incorrect encoding.

I already tried adding encoding="UTF-8" to the javac task, but with no success.

How it can be fixed?

p.s. I know this is quite bad practice to have string literals hardcoded in the source files, but this is situation when I need it there, so please don't suggest to extract it to the resource bundle.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Are you sure your source files are stored in UTF-8?

Comment: Yes, I did a double check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not actually an answer to original problem, but I don't want this question to be unanswered. Maybe moderators will decide to delete it. Anyway.

Looks like this is some kind of bug when using specific combination of ant, jdk, windows.
I dug really deep and wasn't able to fix this in a let's say normal way.

So I decided to externalize string to properties file, which is anyway better practice...

Normally solution suggested by Mikhail Vladimirov should work fine, but not this time.

Answer (score 1):

Proper way is

```
<javac ... encoding="UTF-8" ... />
```

If in resulting class files strings are in incorrect encoding, it means that probably your source encoding is not UTF-8, or these files are compiled by some other `javac` task, not the one you modified.

Comment: I did it and did double check that sources is in UTF-8. It didn't help. And I have only one javac task in my ant file, so I don't think this is the reason.

Answer (score 0):

The encoding must match the encoding of the file. Your guess of utf-8 may not be correct.  Please check other [suitable encoding names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859-1) like iso-8859-1.

Please check upvoted answers in [How do I set -Dfile.encoding within ant's build.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339352/how-do-i-set-dfile-encoding-within-ants-build-xml)