# Ant Build failed in eclipse, but from command prompt it is successfull

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I am getting error as:

error: unmappable character for encoding UTF8
    [javac]         // url encoded is '�' which will get properly url encoded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify ant to add this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<project name="test" default="compile">
    <target name="compile">
        <javac srcdir="src" destdir="classes" 
                           encoding="cp1252" debug="true" />
    </target>
</project>
```

Read this for more details: http://www.weblogism.com/item/288/unmappable-character-for-encoding-utf8

Comment: thank you for the response. Actually it is a read only file. i can't edit the file

Comment: Oh, then try adding `java.encoding=utf-8` to your build.properties file.

Comment: Wait, Is this Java or Android? For Java source files look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339352/how-do-i-set-dfile-encoding-within-ants-build-xml

Comment: thank you, it is working now without changing anything. In build.properties file java.encoding=utf-8 is already there.