# XML Portlet Factory build error

Tags: liferay, portlet

I followed [this example](http://www.xmlportletfactory.org/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Install+XMLPortletFactory+in+Liferay+SDK) and when I start the command (the instruction of the tutorial) I get the following error:

```
PS C:\repository\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2.0\XMLPortletFactory\example-xmlportletfactory> ant
Buildfile: C:\repository\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2.0\XMLPortletFactory\example-xmlportletfactory\build.xml
     [echo] Generating for SDK version =6.2.0

generate-portlet:
     [java] May 19, 2014 4:37:31 PM org.xmlportletfactory.utils.XMLUtils validateAgainstSchema
     [java] SEVERE: null
     [java] com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.
 ...

BUILD FAILED
C:\repository\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2.0\XMLPortletFactory\example-xmlportletfactory\build.xml:19: Java returned: 1

Total time: 0 seconds
PS C:\repository\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2.0\XMLPortletFactory\example-xmlportletfactory>
```

How to say ant that it use utf-8 encoding? If I change the encoding in the xml I get the following error:

```
PS C:\repository\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2.0\XMLPortletFactory\example-xmlportletfactory> ant
Buildfile: C:\repository\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2.0\XMLPortletFactory\example-xmlportletfactory\build.xml

BUILD FAILED
Encoding of project file C:\repository\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2.0\XMLPortletFactory\example-xmlportletfactory\build.xml is invalid.

Total time: 0 seconds
PS C:\repository\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2.0\XMLPortletFactory\example-xmlportletfactory>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I set -Dfile.encoding within ant's build.xml?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339352/how-do-i-set-dfile-encoding-within-ants-build-xml)

Comment: Yes but it doesnt work, I try to change encoding of the file via notepad++ , pass the the encoding style to ant via option '-Dfile.encoding=' and set the encoding attribute in the xml but it doesnt helps.

Comment: I see my problem I dont realy convert the encoding to certain format. After convertation it works.